# How to match everything outside of brackets and everything inside of brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

These are some demo strings,

```
enum('a', 'b', 'c')
varchar(255)
int unsigned
```

Taking first one as an example, I want to match `enum` and `'a', 'b', 'c'`. Everything inside brackets are optional as you see in 3rd example: `int unsigned`. How do I do this?

I tried,

```
(.*)(\((.*)\))?
```

However this matches whole string for some reason.

```js
const out = /(.*)(\((.*)\))?/.exec(`enum('a', 'b', 'c')`)
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const [, first, second] = /^(.*?)(?:\((.*)\))?$/.exec(`enum('a', 'b', 'c')`)
console.log(first + '\n' + second)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PV8PX/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars **as few as possible**
- `(?:\((.*)\))?` - an optional sequence of `(`, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (captured into Group 2), and then a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tests = [
    "enum('a', 'b', 'c')",
    "varchar(255)",
    "int unsigned"
];

tests.forEach(test => console.log(/([^(]+)(?:\((.*)\))?/.exec(test)));
```

The first capturing group grabs the part before the parenthesis, the second optionally what is contained within the parenthesis if applicable.